# how to add dates into array on selecting from multiDatesPicker and delete on deselecting

Tags: jquery, arrays

i am using this  [multiDatesPicker](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/)

code i am using to add selected dates into array :

```
var disabledDates = [];

$('#custom-methods').multiDatesPicker({
    defaultDate: 0, minDate:" -3m", maxDate: "-1D+1Y", showOtherMonths: true, 
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    selectOtherMonths: true, 
  onSelect: function(selected,evnt) 
  { if($.inArray(selected, disabledDates)<0||disabledDates.length==0){
        disabledDates.push(selected); 
        }
  },
});
```

my project requirement is when i deselect a particular date it should automatically been deleted from array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var disabledDates = [];

$('#custom-methods').multiDatesPicker({
    defaultDate: 0, minDate:" -3m", maxDate: "-1D+1Y", showOtherMonths: true, 
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    selectOtherMonths: true
});

$('#custom-methods').blur(function(){ 
  disabledDates = $(this).val().split(',');
  console.log(disabledDates);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="custom-methods" value="">
```

Can you please check the code. I used **BlUR** from *jquery* to get the value from and inserted to an array.
Hope it will help you thanks

Comment: BlUR is not working in my code for adding selected dates into array and how about deleting elements from array on deselection.

Comment: When you use blur it will give you the current date selected on the calendar and if you unselect any date it will automatically removed from array. 
You try onblur in your code. it think it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

```js
var disabledDates = [];

$('#custom-methods').multiDatesPicker({
    defaultDate: 0, minDate:" -3m", maxDate: "-1D+1Y", showOtherMonths: true, 
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    selectOtherMonths: true, 
  onClose: function(selected,evnt) 
  { 
disabledDates = $(this).val().split(',');
console.log(disabledDates);
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="custom-methods" value="">
```

Try this code instead, this code is fragmented as per you approach

Comment: your  code is working fine for popup datepicker but i am using an inline calendar for which onclose method will not work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle example so that i can help you over that

Comment: your code worked fine actually there was some jquery version difference because of which it was not working.

Comment: instead of onclose i  wrote onSelect().